# Do I count Math.max in a Big O Runtime?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, max, big-o, min

I have trouble in understanding weather or not using Math.max should be counted as a loop, therefore should be included in calculating Big O runtime.

I assume for the Math.max to find the max value it has to loop and compare through all the values it was provided. Therefore it is actually looping.

My code in JS:

```
function getWaterCapacityPerSurface(surface){
    let waterAmount = 0;

    // full loop
    for(let i = 1; i < surface.length - 1; i++){
        const current = surface[i];

        // I assume each slice is counted as a half of the full loop
        const leftSlice = surface.slice(0, (i - 1 < 0 ? 0 : i));
        const rightSlice = surface.slice(i + 1, surface.length);

        // I assume each Math.max is counted as a half of the full loop
        const leftBound = Math.max(...leftSlice);
        const rightBound = Math.max(...rightSlice);

        const canWaterStay = leftBound > current && rightBound > current;
        const currentBound = Math.min(leftBound, rightBound);
        const waterLevel = currentBound - current;

        if(canWaterStay) waterAmount += waterLevel;
    }

    return waterAmount;
}

console.log(getWaterCapacityPerSurface([4,2,1,3,0,1,2]));
// returns 6
```

Is Big O runtime O(N(N+N)) or O(N(N))?

I assume in this case it doesn't really matter because we drop constants and at the end it is going to be O(N(N+N)) = O(N(2N)) = O(N(N)) = O(N²)
But I just would like to know weather I should count Math.max/Math.min as a loop for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you pass a list of arguments of length `n` to `Math.max()`, then it is an *O(n)* operation. `Math.max()` iterates through every argument. See more info in the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.max).